# Animated post apocalyptic movie with soldier made from decaying tissue

Tags: identify-this-movie

In the early 90s I watched an animated movie about black hollow soldiers fighting on earth. They were made of decaying tissue from people thrown into some big vat or a cave. people/prisoners were transported inside big eggs. A couple, man and a woman, escaped by tossing a seed which grew into thorn like plant and cracked the shell.

There was also transporting "bird" basically two wings(flying wing organic plane like device) made of human tissue that was used as transport. The thing died at the end of the flight. I think it carried them to a group that spoke in past and future at the same time but never in present.  Ultimately they have agreed on a war speaking in present time.

They somehow broke into the black soldier factory where these were being assembled and removed a vital piece from inside of helmets. It was a red ball/egg tissue organic computer.

The soldiers look like hollow medieval armor but with a futuristic design.

Comment: What do you mean by "a group that spoke in past and future at the same time but never in present" and "Ultimately they have agreed on a war speaking in present time"?

Comment: I have watched it dubbed, therefore this may have been a stretch of a description.

Comment: Heavy Metal. The jungle of crashed airplanes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Gandahar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandahar_(film)), (1988), was a French animated science fiction and fantasy film.  There was also an English language version released as **Light Years**.

> The peaceful people of Gandahar are suddenly attacked by an army of
>   automatons known as the Men of Metal, who march through the villages
>   and kidnap their victims by turning them to stone. The resulting
>   statues are collected and then transferred to their base.
>
> ...
>
> Sylvain later saves Airelle, a Gandaharian woman. Together they
>   discover the Men of Metal’s base, where the frozen Gandaharians are
>   taken through a large portal and are seemingly assimilated into more
>   Men of Metal.

[French](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cfCRreaVxw) and [English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eucpelkpuiY) versions are available on Youtube.  The scene where Sylvain removes a red ball/egg from the head of a metal man is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cfCRreaVxw#t=1469).

Comment: RIGHT ON!!!!!! I have searched for this for years!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Which part of my babbling description was helpful?

Comment: @Kalasinus "Black hollow soldiers" and "people thrown into some big vat".

Comment: Gandahar "was" a film? You mean Gandahar "was-will be" a film ;)